# Overridden /usr/bin/php. How to restore?

Tags: php, macos

Hy,

I've accidentally override the /usr/bin/php file, and can't get back the originally one.

Is there any solutions to restore it?

I'm using OSX 10.9.3.

Thanks, Dave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it help if I just gave you mine? Also running Mavericks 10.9.3. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3261971/php

You could also just reinstall OS X if you have some spare time or restore from backup as mentioned in other answers in this topic.

Another option would be to extract it from the Mavericks Installer using [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com).

Comment: I think it would be ok, but I'm only get the content of the file instead of download it.
Unfortunately I don't have the installer, I got the MAC without it :\

Comment: you can use wget or curl in the terminal to download it ;)

`curl https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3261971/php -o php`

Then copy it to the original location using cp:
`sudo cp php /usr/bin/php`

Comment: Really thanks. I've totally forgotten curl. Now every path is the good path. Thank's for the help.

Comment: No problem. If you ever need the OS X Installer, you can download it from the Mac App Store: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id675248567?mt=12

Answer (score 1):

The solutions are the same as for any other overwritten file:

- Restore from your regular backups (you are using Apple Time Machine, aren't you?)
- Get a clean version from wherever you got the original from

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TimeMachine you must have a backup. Else you must reinstall/recompile PHP.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not using TimeMachine :\
How can I reinstall/recompile PHP? (I'm using Homebrew)

Comment: As you are using Mac OS it can be a little hard to get php bin back...
May be you can simply install MAMP and copy its PHP binary ?
http://www.mamp.info/en/

Comment: it seems to be ok, but now everything is pointing to MAMP's folder (ini file, include path, etc.)

Comment: Yes but just copy the PHP bin to /usr/bin and then delete all MAMP folder :)
See below answer. DJFLiX seems to have a better solution.